# Is there a syntactically short way to initialize a struct pointer on heap?

Tags: c, struct

When I have:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char* key;
} some_pthread_arg;
```

I could say:

```
some_pthread_arg spa1 = 
  {
   .id = 123456, 
   .key = "Hello World!" // is it a problem, that i don't predefine the input size?
  };
```

And if I want to initialize a pointer on such a struct, I could simply:

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2 = &spa1;
```

instead of:

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2;
spa2->id = 123456;
spa2->key = "Hello World!"; // is it a problem, that i don't predefine the input size?
```

But If I use this:

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2 = &spa1;
```

I don't have any chance to allocate the structure on heap, whereas with the other option I could:

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2 = (some_pthread_arg *) malloc (sizeof(some_pthread_arg));
spa2->id = 123456;
spa2->key = "Hello World!"; // is it a problem, that i don't predefine the input size?
```

So long story short, is there something similar to the following?

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2 = (some_pthread_arg *) malloc (sizeof(some_pthread_arg));
spa2 = 
  { 
   ->id = 123456,
   ->key = "Hello World" // is it a problem, that i don't predefine the input size?
  };
```

Comment: why `key` is pointing to `string` being `int *`?

Comment: `is it a problem, that i don't predefine the input size?` – the member is a pointer, so for the `struct` the size (the string length) is irrelevant.

Comment: @kiranBiradar sorry that was a mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a compound literal:

```
some_pthread_arg *spa2 = malloc(sizeof *spa2);
if (!spa2) Handle error...
*spa2 = (some_pthread_arg) { .id = 12345, .key = "Hello, world!" };
```

Notes:

- In C, you do not need to cast the result of `malloc`.
- `malloc(sizeof *spa2)` is better than `malloc(sizeof(some_pthread_arg))` because, if the type of `spa2` is changed, a single edit suffices, whereas the latter requires multiple edits and becomes a bug if somebody misses one of them.